# Symfony2 multiple relationships between two entities

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I've two entities: Product and ProductAttachment (a file entity)

A product have a main photo, a list of pictures and a list of documents.

My idea is to have tree relationships between Product and ProductAttachment, so i've three attribute in Product:

- $main_photo : OneToOne
- $pictures : OneToMany
- $attachments : OneToMany

The product attachment have this attributes:

- $name
- $path
- $file
- $product : ManytoOne
- $type : type of attachment (main photo, picture, document)

I've some problems, but before ask specific questions i want to know if it's a good approach.

Does exist another easy way to work with files? 
I've tried some upload bundles in knpbundles without luck (they don't fit my needed)

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: After re-reading your question, in relation to your relationships, you'd actually need
ManyToOne (Because you can have many products with one main image attached)
ManyToMany (Many products + many pictures)
ManyToMany (Many products + many attachments)

Then you'd have the inverses as a OneToMany, ManyToMany and ManyToMany.

It might also be possible to have both the pictures and attachments in one relationship and a type identifier on the file, it's really up to you.

END EDIT

The way you've done it will work, generally when I'm working with files that database structure pretty much stays the same. The product attachment(or file) might have some extra fields indicating where it's stored(FTP, S3, etc) but apart from that identical.

Normally when I'm working with a file to upload I use a script like http://www.plupload.com which actually posts the image to a page of your choice. It's really good as it'll use HTML5 and fall back to various other uploader types if the user doenst have the support for that uploader.

When the uploader sends a response to the controller, it'll send files, normally I have a route setup that lets me specify a upload directory so I'd be pointing the uploader to say http://site.com/upload/upload-folder1

Then you get the controller to save the file, and send back a response with the location of the file. You then use javascript to put the file location into a hidden form field productAttachment.path(for example) and that's pretty much it.

I also tried the upload bundles but they were fairly complicated and seemed to lack what I needed exactly.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the response.
First problem: in ProductAttachment i don't know what to put in the inversedBy clause of the relationship because there are three attributes in Product (main_photo, pictures, documents):

@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="???")

Comment: I've re-dited my main post to reflect after re-reading your question.

Comment: Thank you, by the way i've found the right way to do it using the DiscriminatorMap syntax. A MappedSuperclass with the DiscriminatorMap and two class (ProductPicture and ProductDocument) that extend it and have two different definition of $product:
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="picture")
and
@ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Product", inversedBy="documents")